# How to write a good and efficient makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have following folder structure:

```
TOPDIR
|
├── a
│   ├── a.c
│   ├── a.h
│   └── a.mk
├── b
│   ├── b.c
│   ├── b.h
│   └── b.mk
├── c
│   ├── c.c
│   ├── c.h
│   └── c.mk
├── include
│   └── common.h
├── root
│    ├── main.c
│    └── root.mk
└── Makefile
```

**per-condition**

My target is to write main `Makefile` under `TOPDIR` and sub-makefile, `*.mk` in sub folder, the `include` folder contain some common defines. `root` folder contain my main file(`main` function located here). Meanwhile, in `main.c`, it will call function from `a.c` and `b.c`, `c.c` is driver related, and will be called from `a.c` and `b.c`

**Problem**

I wrote sub-makefile like(I use one `a.mk` for example, others are same, ONLY `root.mk` has little different):

```
#MODULE will be modified for each sub folder
MODULE = a
LIB = $(MAKE_DIR)/libs/lib$(MODULE).a
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

#generate lib file from obj file
$(LIB): $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p ../libs
    @$(AR) cr $@ $^
    @echo "    Archive    $(notdir $@)"

#compile obj file from source file
$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^
    @echo "    CC        $(OBJS)"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(RM) -f $(LIB) $(OBJS)
    @$(RM) -f *.expand
    @echo "    Remove Objects:   $(OBJS)"
    @echo "    Remove Libraries:  $(notdir $(LIB))"
```

I wrote `root.mk` like:

```
PROG = ../prog/DEMO

SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

#generate finial target file for run
$(PROG): $(SRCS)
    @mkdir -p ../prog
    @$(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) -Wl,-Map=$(PROG).map $(LIBS) -o $@
    @echo "    Generate Program $(notdir $(PROG)) from $^"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(RM) -f $(OBJS) $(PROG)
    @$(RM) -f *.expand
    @$(RM) -rf ../prog ../libs
    @echo "    Remove Objects:   $(OBJS)"
    @echo "    Remove Libraries:  $(notdir $(PROG))"
```

I wrote main `Makefile` like:

```
MAKE_DIR = $(PWD)

ROOT_DIR    := $(MAKE_DIR)/root 
DRV_DIR     := $(MAKE_DIR)/driver
INCLUDE_DIR := $(MAKE_DIR)/include
DEBUG_DIR   := $(MAKE_DIR)/debug

INC_SRCH_PATH := 
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(ROOT_DIR)
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(DRV_DIR) 
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(DEBUG_DIR)

LIB_SRCH_PATH :=
LIB_SRCH_PATH += -L$(MAKE_DIR)/libs

CC = gcc
LD = ld

#problem happan here, if I change the sequence of LIB, 
#during the finial link, it will find some function un-referenced, 
#why can I put liba first?
LIBS := -lc -lb -la

CFLAGS :=
CFLAGS += $(INC_SRCH_PATH) $(LIB_SRCH_PATH) 
CFLAGS += -Wall -O -ggdb
CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -D_REENTRANT

LDFLAGS :=

export MAKE_DIR CC LD CFLAGS LDFLAGS LIBS LINT INC_SRCH_PATH

all:
    @$(MAKE) -C a -f a.mk
    @$(MAKE) -C b -f b.mk
    @$(MAKE) -C c -f c.mk
    @$(MAKE) -C root -f root.mk

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(MAKE) -C debug -f debug.mk clean
    @$(MAKE) -C driver -f driver.mk clean
    @$(MAKE) -C mw -f mw.mk clean
    @$(MAKE) -C root -f root.mk clean
```

**Question**

1. In main `Makefile`, I define which `LIB` file I will use, if need move it to `root.mk` for better?
2. In sub-makefile, I did NOT use `-MM` to generate depend file, if this cause the problem I can NOT change the sequence of my `lib*`, which I also described in `Makefile` comments.
3. Seems my makefile system can NOT detect I update some head file, for example, I first compiled whole code, and then, I modified one head file, when I try to re-compile, none of source is compiled

if:

```
#Automatic dependency magic:
%.d: src/%.c
   $(CC) -MM -o$@ $<

-include (MYPROG_OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)
```

need add into each sub-makefile?

Comment: Always worth reading when new to Makefiles. [Recursive make considered harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule is definitely wrong:

```
$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
        @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^
        @echo "    CC        $(OBJS)"
```

The target line will expand to something like:

```
a.o b.o c.o d.o : a.c b.c c.c d.c
```

That's not right.  It is identical to writing this:

```
a.o : a.c b.c c.c d.c
        ...
b.o : a.c b.c c.c d.c
        ...
c.o : a.c b.c c.c d.c
        ...
d.o : a.c b.c c.c d.c
        ...
```

This means that whenever you change any source file, ALL the object files will be rebuilt.  You should use a pattern rule here:

```
%.o : %.c
        @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
        @echo "    CC        $@"
```

to compile the object files one at a time.

As far as your questions go, I don't understand question #1.

Questions #2 and #3 (if I understand correctly) are the same thing: the reason for #3 (no files are recompiled when you change a header file) is that you're not declaring any prerequisites on header files.  Make doesn't have any built-in support for this, so you either have to do it by hand (add `a.o : a.c b.h c.h g.h` to your makefiles) or else automatically generate the dependencies.

The dependency generation will typically use the `-MM` or similar flags, assuming your compiler supports these flags.

Comment: if I use `%o:%c`, need I still define `$(OBJS)` and `$(SRCS)`?

Comment: meanwhile, how to write `lib` file generation? use `%a:%o`?

Comment: You need `OBJS` because you need to have `$(LIB)` depend on them.  You need `SRCS` so you can compute `OBJS`.  So yes.  For libraries, you can just write an explicit rule.  The pattern rule you suggest won't work well for the most part since it says "build a `.a` file from _one_ `.o` file", which is not how libraries are built.  You can do it with patterns but since you typically only build one library per makefile anyway it's usually not worth it.

Comment: I just use a very simple folder tree and files, my main idea is I split code into different function module, and each dedicate module will locate in a sub-folder and during compile, can be generated out a `lib` file, after I generated ALL module's `lib`, I link them together with my `main` function files. You said this is NOT how `lib` are build, so can you give more suggestion on how to organize or generate `lib` file?

Comment: SO comments are not the place to have long discussions about things like this.  You can ask for help on the help-make@gnu.org mailing list.  However, that's not what I said.  What I said was when you build a library you don't create it (normally) from a single object file, you create it from a group of object files.  Pattern rules _usually_ define ways to create a single output file from a single input file (e.g., compiling a source file into an object file).  So, pattern rules are not usually a good fit for creating libraries.