# recursive build or not for writing makefile

Tags: makefile

[My previsou question for sub-folder makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297968/how-to-write-a-good-and-efficiency-makefile)

```
TOPDIR
|
├── a
│   ├── a.c
│   └── a.h
├── b
│   ├── b.c
│   └── b.h
├── c
│   ├── c.c
│   └── c.h
├── include
│   └── common.h
├── root
│    └──main.c
└── Makefile
```

above is my project file tree view, and I wrote some `makefile` but seems it has follow problem:

- it can NOT identify if I modified some head files during recompile

You can find my previous `makefile` according to the TOP link, now I wan to change my `makefile` style, and I want to achieve following things:

- ONLY one `makefile` in `TOPDIR` and this `makefile` can first get ALL source files under my project tree and then compile them.
- I need generate a good dependency, so that, it can help make to identify if I update some head file during re-compile

Any suggestions or example?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a dependency generation tool, e.g. makedepend (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend ) or one of the -M options to gcc (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options ) if you're using that to generate a dependency file which you then include from your makefile. Ideally, have one dependency file per output file, and have the dependency file list both the dependencies for the output file and for itself (i.e. have each line repeated once for the object file and once for the dependency file). That way, your dependency files will automatically be re-generated whenever necessary. Something like this:

```
SOURCES=#...
DEPS=$(addprefix .dep/,$(addsuffix .mk,$(SOURCES))
-include $(DEPS)
.dep:
  mkdir .dep
.dep/%.mk: | .dep
  # Rule for generating the .dep/foo.c.mk, which holds both dependencies for
  # foo.c and .dep/foo.c.mk
```